# Write files with multiple columns to array

Tags: python, list

I have several files with x and y values and I want to plot them simultaniously into one graph.
For this, I want to make a loop in which the program writes the x-data and the y-data, so that I have in the end an array which look like this:

```
results=[[x1],[y1],[x2],[y2],....]
```

Afterwards I want to plot all data in one graph but with different colors. And this automatically.

Edit: my code looks at the moment like this:

```
#Program to show FFT intensitys of interfering waves with phase difference
path='pah_to_files'
files=['0pi.txt','0.25pi.txt','0.5pi.txt','0.75pi.txt','1pi.txt']

#read data
for i in range (len(files)):
    data=np.loadtxt(path+'/'+files[i], usecols=(0,1))
    position=data[:,0] #first column is position
    intensity=data[:,1] #second column is intensity
```

I know that this loop reads the files, but it always overwrites the previous position and intensity data.

Comment: can you give an example of your inputs? and of your expected outputs? and did you try something so far? A good hint on how to write a good question is [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is there a reason you want your array data to look like that? If you are using matplotlib to plot things then it expects a X array and a separate Y array.

Answer (score 1):

The better way to get it done is with `zip`, like this:

```
x_values = [1,2,3,4,5]
y_values = ['a','b','c','d']
pairs_of_values = zip(x_values, y_values)
```

Now `pairs_of_values[0]` will be a *tuple* `(1,'a')`.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines could be used to popoulate the result list in the way you said the result should have:

```
results = [];
for x in range(10):
    y = x*x
    results.append([x])
    results.append([y])

print results
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm using Python for 4 days now and I think I have to be more careful about lists and arrays.... The following code solved my problem with reading the files.

```
#Program to show FFT intensitys of interfering waves with phase difference
path='pah_to_files'
files=['0pi.txt','0.25pi.txt','0.5pi.txt','0.75pi.txt','1pi.txt']

results=[]

#read data
for i in range (len(files)): #all files which are tortured the folloing way
data=np.loadtxt(path+'/'+files[i], usecols=(0,1))

results.append(data[:,0]) #x-position
results.append(data[:,1]) #intensity
```